# Retrofit Response in Android

Tags: android, string, retrofit

What is the difference betweeen `string()` and `toString()` for Retrofit Response ?

Can any tell the difference in details.

```
 response.body().string();

 response.body().toString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.body().string();` returns response body converted to String. JSON, for example.

`response.body().toString();` returns string look of ResponseBody object. It hash, class ...

Answer (score 0):

`response.body().toString();` - Convert object responseBody(body()) to string

`return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

`response.body().string();` - Convert response from server to string;

Answer (score 0):

`.toString():` This returns your object in string format.

`.string():` This returns your response.